# Lottery program is stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, validation, user-input, infinite-loop

I'm creating a lottery program, and I used a set class I created instead of the java set.

Heres's my Set class; it does the basic functions of a Java set

```java
import java.util.*;

public class mySet<T>
{
    private Set<T> yourSet=new HashSet<T>();
    T number;
    mySet()
    {
    }

    private mySet(Set<T> yourSet)
    {
        this.yourSet=yourSet;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            System.out.println("Your set is empty");
        else
            System.out.println(yourSet);
    }
    //public
    public void addToSet(T number)
    {
        this.number=number;
        yourSet.add(number);
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (yourSet==null);

    }

    public int getCardinality()
    {
        int size=0;
        size=yourSet.size();
        return(size);
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        yourSet.clear();
    }

    public boolean isInSet(int value)
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("The set is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            yourSet.contains(value);
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public mySet <T>intersection(mySet<T> setb)
    {
        Set<T> newSet=new HashSet<>(yourSet);
        newSet.retainAll(setb.yourSet);
        return new mySet<>(newSet);
    }
}
```

Here's the program that gets and validates the user's input

```java
public mySet userLottery(mySet userStore){
    
    for (int x=0;x<6;x++)
    {
        int user=getUser("Please enter your lottery number : ");

        if(userStore.isInSet(user) )// checks if the number entered by the user have been entered before
        {
            x--;
            System.out.println("No duplicates are allowed");
            continue;
        }
        else if (user>=LOTTERY_MAX )// checks if the user entered a number that is higher than the Lottery max
        {
            x--;
            System.out.println("The value you entered must be lower than the limit "+"("+LOTTERY_MAX+")");
            continue;
        }
        else if (user<1 )//prevents the user from entering a number less than 1
        {
            x--;
            System.out.println("The value you entered must be greater than 0");
            continue;
        }

        else
        {
            userStore.addToSet(user);// adds the users input to the Set if it meets all conditions

        }
    }

    System.out.println("this is the users input : "+userStore);//prints out the users input
    return userStore;
}
```

`LOTTERY_MAX` is the maximum range of the lottery number, and the user selects the range.

When I run the program and input numbers, it prints out no duplicates allowed, and it's stuck in an infinite loop somehow. I tried clearing the set from the start, but the same issue continues. When I removed the if statements, the program runs as expected, but then there is nothing to validate the user's input. The program is meant to take user input put it in a set, cross-check it against a set of computer-generated numbers.

Comment: mySet has several bugs. Probably isEmpty is wrong, your set can be non null and still empty. isInSet does not check the return of contains, it always return true. So I suspect your set is empty but not null, so isEmpty() return false, which causes isInSet to always return true.

Comment: (1) you should use proper indentation, (2) your `mySet.isInSet` function always returns `true` when the set is not empty. It doesn't actually check if the provided value is in the set. (3) updating a `for` loop counter is bad practice (i.e. the `x--` thing). (4) you should try to trace through this thing with a debugger.

Comment: `x--;` why are you decrementing you variable? You should also learn to use the Auto-Formatter in your IDE.

Comment: @MattClark because they want 6 numbers, and thus decrement x to indicate that this input 'does not count' as it is faulty.

Comment: From the few details you have provided, it sounds like `getUser` is probably the culprit, but you didn't paste that code.

Comment: @rzwitserloot getUser uses a Genio object to get the users input, it doesn't do anything else so I don't think it's the problem

Comment: @obe what do you mean by proper indentation I'm using bluej as my idle,  do I have to fix isInSet or just go straight to isEmpty, and rzwitser loot is right the for loop runs 6 times and if the number isn't correct  x should be decreased by 1 since during each iteration it is increased by 1

Comment: I mean the difference between before and after Mark Rotteveel edited your question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67437080/revisions. I'm not sure I understand your other question. There seem to be multiple problems with the code. I suggest that you go through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (yourSet==null);

}
```

this is not how you would check if your set is empty or not. This is how you'd like to do it:

```
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (yourSet==null || yourSet.isEmpty());

}
```

EDIT: I don't understand why you are wrapping `HashSet` instead using it directly. You would have avoided so many problems if you did that. Those classes exist for a reason. Learn to utilize them properly.